# url hyperlink in gantt chart

Tags: url, gantt

I would like to embed an online url such as `www.google.com` in a gantt chart with `\href{}{}`. Unfortunately, this does not work for me. The links never become clickable.

Reproducible example can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359167/how-to-make-a-href-in-one-gantt-chart-clickable-to-a-label/586583#586583)

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Try replacing `\hyperref[task1]{Task1}` with `\href{www.google.com}{Task1}`

Comment: Hmmm.. in Texpad, this does not work for me. The link is not clickable but the label shows up correctly